# Inline form validation using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the jQuery Validation configuration from the [Runningcoder](http://www.runningcoder.org/jqueryvalidation/) website.

I have setup my signup form and it is validating the form ok. The problem I have is when I click submit on the form, nothing happens. The form I am using is:

```
<form id="form-signup_v2" name="form-signup_v2" method="post" class="validation-form-container" action="index.php">

<div class="field">
    <label for="signup_v2-firstname">First Name</label>
    <div class="ui left labeled input">
        <input id="signup_v2-firstname" name="signup_v2[firstname]" type="text" data-validation="[NOTEMPTY, NAME, L&gt;=2, TRIM]" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Firstname" data-validation-message="Please enter your firstname.">
        <div class="ui corner label">
            <i class="asterisk icon"></i>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <label for="signup_v2-lastname">Last Name</label>
    <div class="ui left labeled input">
        <input id="signup_v2-lastname" name="signup_v2[lastname]" type="text" data-validation="[NOTEMPTY, NAME, L&gt;=2, TRIM]" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Surname" data-validation-message="Please enter your surname.">
        <div class="ui corner label">
            <i class="asterisk icon"></i>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <label for="signup_v2-email">Email</label>
    <div class="ui left labeled input">

        <input id="signup_v2-email" name="signup_v2[email]" type="text" data-validation="[EMAIL]">

        <div class="ui corner label">
            <i class="asterisk icon"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <label for="signup_v2-email-confirm">Confirm Email</label>
    <div class="ui left labeled input">

        <input id="signup_v2-email-confirm" name="signup_v2[email-confirm]" type="text" data-validation="[V==signup_v2[email]]" data-validation-message="Your email address does not match.">
        <div class="ui corner label">
            <i class="asterisk icon"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <div class="ui checkbox">
        <input id="signup_v2-agree" name="signup_v2[agree]" data-validation="[NOTEMPTY]" data-validation-message="Please accept the terms and conditions." type="checkbox">
        <label class="checkbox" for="signup_v2-agree">I agree the <a href="#">terms and conditions</a></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the script I am using immediately below the form on the page is:

```
<script>             
$.validate({
submit: {
    settings: {
        form: '#form-signup_v2',
        inputContainer: '.field',
        errorListClass: 'ui red pointing below label'
    },
    callback: {
        onSubmit: function (node, formData) {
            console.log('~~~~~~~~~')
            console.log(node)
            console.log(formData)
            console.log('~~~~~~~~~')
        }
    }
},
dynamic: {
    settings: {
        trigger: 'focusout'
    },
    callback: {
        onSuccess: function (node, input, keyCode) {
            if ($(input).val()) {
$(input).parent().find('.ui.corner.label').removeClass('red').addClass('green');
            }
        },
        onError: function (node, input, keyCode, error) {
            $(input).parent().find('.ui.corner.label').removeClass('green');
        }
    }
}
});             
</script>
```

Hopefully this is an easy fix for somebody out there?!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://www.runningcoder.org/jqueryvalidation/#callbacks):

`settings.callback.onSubmit`

> Will be executed if no errors are found.
>
> - Careful, using this callback will override the native HTML form.submit() and prevent the form from submitting by default.

Your `settings.callback.onSubmit` calls only `console.log`. Do you see anything in the JavaScript console? What happens if you replace `onSubmit` with `onBeforeSubmit`?

Comment: Thanks szym. I've updated the script to remove the entire onSumbit block, as I don't really need it anyway. Now I get "Uncaught TypeError: node[0].submit is not a function" in the console when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help szym. I figured out there were 2 issues.

1) The settings.callback.onSubmit was not necessary for what I was doing so I removed it from the block.

2) The Submit button should not have had an ID or Name attribute of submit.